# Why does it say Global Name not Defined when it is? Python

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I am scripting a very simple guess the animal game where the player does the guessing. I have taken a long time to imput all the information and I know that it is very long-winded and could probably be done in much shorter ways but I am a beginner. The thing is, part of it is not working. I will put the code in and highlight the areas that arn't working and explain what happens....

```
def animalmenu():
    print()
    print()
    print('Welcome to the menu. I am thinking of an animal. Select the option\'s below to try and guess my animal.')
    print()
    print('a) No. of Legs')
    print('b) Type of animal')
    print('c) Preffered Climate')
    print('d) Size')
    print('e) Colour')
    print('f) Diet')
    print('g) Habitat')
    print('h) Can be kept as pet')
    print('i) Guess the animal')
    print()
    AniChoice = input('Choose your option: ')
    if AniChoice == 'a':
        choicea()
    if AniChoice == 'b':
        choiceb()
    if AniChoice == 'c':
        choicec()
    if AniChoice == 'd':
        choiced()
    if AniChoice == 'e':
        choicee()
    elif AniChoice == 'f':
        choicef()
    elif AniChoice == 'g':
        choiceg()
    elif AniChoice == 'h':
        choiceh()
    elif AniChoice == 'i':
        guessing()
```

So that is the basic lay out of the menu. Then for each option there is a sub-menu, for example:

```
def choicea():
    print()
    print('')
    print()
    guessleg = input('Guess the number of legs (insects may be listed as \'lots\': ')
    if leg == guessleg:
        print('True')
        print('r = Return to menu, g = guess again.')

    elif leg != guessleg:
        print('False')
        print('r = Return to menu, g = guess again.')
```

These sub-menu's work fine till you get to sub-menu's f to i... I don't know what is wrong. You get the data that you are trying to guess from another area of the code which goes like this...

```
def animalchoice():
    asdf = ('dog', 'monkey', 'parrot', 'fox', 'mouse', 'lady-bird', 'badger', 'shark', 'whale', 'pigeon')
    from random import choice
    animal = choice(asdf)
    if animal == 'dog':
        leg = '4'
        breed = 'mammal'
        climate = 'any'
        size = 'dog+'
        colour = 'depends'
        diet = 'a'
        habitat = 'ground'
        pet = 'yes'

    if animal == 'monkey':
        leg = '4'
        breed = 'mammal'
        climate = 'hot'
        size = 'dog+'
        colour = 'brown'
        diet = 'c'
        habitat = 'tree'
        pet = 'no'
```

this continues for more animals. When I run the script, it works fine. I have added loops etc. in different places and it's fine. But when I try and run say option g from the menu (def choiceg) it comes up with all sorts of errors, basically saying that the global name'habitat' (the thing we're trying to guess in that particular area) is not defined. I have coded those areas in the same way as the other areas and yet it won't work... what am I doing wrong? aside from the long winded way of scripting....
Help!?!?! How do I prevent the errors???

Comment: Whenever faced with very long and repetitive bits of coding like this you should take a step back and think whether there's a neater way to do it. In this case:

`mapping = {"a": choicea, "b": choiceb, ...};
mapping[input()]()`

will work the same and avoid the tremendous mess of `if` statements. I think the data in your second code section would probably best be stored in a separate file, so that the code and the data aren't conflated.

Comment: You *do* know this cries out for the use of data structures instead of all this hardcoded stuff, right? And that writing it this way makes it harder to maintain and verify, and for that matter, harder to write in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define those variables, you're setting them *within those functions*. They're not actually global variables at all. Your main choices are to

1. configure them as global variables,
2. create "state" objects to pass around (like setting `data['habitat'] = 'tree'` and returning that from the `animalchoice` function),
3. put the functions inside a class and store your values as class variables, like:

`class GuessingGame(object):
    [...]
    def animalchoice(self):
        asdf = ('dog', 'monkey', 'parrot', 'fox', 'mouse', 'lady-bird', 'badger', 'shark', 'whale', 'pigeon')
        from random import choice
        animal = choice(asdf)
        if animal == 'dog':
            self.leg = '4'
            self.breed = 'mammal'
            self.climate = 'any'
            self.size = 'dog+'`

I can't tell you which one is "best" because that will depend on how you want to structure the rest of your program.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the other answers, you can restructure your code to something like:

```
from random import choice

data = {
    "dog": dict(
        leg = '4',
        breed = 'mammal',
        climate = 'any',
        size = 'dog+',
        colour = 'depends',
        diet = 'a',
        habitat = 'ground',
        pet = 'yes',
    ),

    "monkey": dict(
        leg = '4',
        breed = 'mammal',
        climate = 'hot',
        size = 'dog+',
        colour = 'brown',
        diet = 'c',
        habitat = 'tree',
        pet = 'no',
    ),
    # <<Add animals here>> ....
}

data["animal"] = data[choice(data.keys())]    # Current random animal

def animalmenu():
    choices = {
        "a": ("No. of Legs", "leg"),
        "b": ("Type of animal", "breed"),
        "c": ("Preffered Climate", "climate"),
        "d": ("Size", "size"),
        "e": ("Colour", "colour"),
        # <<add attributes here>>...
    }

    while True:
        for k, v in choices.items():
            print "%s) %s" % (k, v[0])

        option = raw_input('Choose your option: ')
        if not option:
            break

        if option in choices:
            guess_attr(choices[option][0], choices[option][1])

        print


def guess_attr(caption, attr):
    global data

    while True:
        guess = str(raw_input('Guess the %s :' % caption))
        ok = guess==str(data["animal"][attr])
        print ok
        if ok:
            break

        option = raw_input('r = Return to menu, g = guess again: ')
        if option=="r":
            break

    print


animalmenu()
```

This way, you can add animals and attributes easily without having to modify all the code.

Comment: +1: This is a much better, more maintainable approach. Want a database backend? Populate `data` with results from an SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

A global variable is a variable that applies to the whole program. In your example, you say that habitat doesn't work, returning the error Global variable not initialized. It means that you might have declared habitat in some other function, maybe choicea, but you since you defined it in choicea, only choicea can access it. In other words, its not global. If you wanted it to be global, you should declare it outside of any functions, and, just to be safe, out of the loops too. Sometimes weird things happen with variables. Its a mistake everyone makes at some point in their programming life.

Also, instead of listing all that in your program, may I suggest using seperate files for them? Or a database to hold the values? This way, you don't have to modify the code every time that you want to change what the values start as... just a friendly suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Been there, made that mistake :-)
Define your global variable (eg. habitat) and 'global' at the beginning of each function that uses it.

A quick google came up with the following article:

http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-you-set-a-global-variable-in-a-function.htm

Also look up 'global' in the python docs for the full explanation/description.

(btw, I think the tabulation was a bit broken when you copied your code into Stackoverflow)

Comment: but the global variable does just that, it varies randomly according to what animal is chosen so I don't see how I could insert it before each thing without typing out... if animal == 'dog': etc, for 30 different animals which would be very tedious and long-winded and be before every sub-menu... how would you suggest doing it? sorry that was long-winded

Comment: As Kirk says, using the variable in a function without the local global definition simply creates a new local variable that 'masks' the global variable that you want to use.